# why z index is not working with fixed and child element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to send my child element to bottom of stack layer, but in output its coming at top instead of the loading code
https://jsfiddle.net/6qop5vtL/1/

here is my code

```
.loadermask { 
    position:absolute; 
    z-index: 900;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.se-pre-con {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background:url(https://transfast.com/Projects/Transfast.UI/img/loadingimg.gif) center no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: You've gotta be a little more specific and show your HTML here.

Comment: A child cannot display below a positioned parent. You might want to read about the [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context). (Look at the example, and observe DIV #3)

Answer (score 1):

Change your HTML to:

```
<div class="se-pre-con">
</div>
<div class="loadermask">
</div>
```

When `loadermask` is a child of `se-pre-con`, its z-index isn't relative to the entire DOM, its relative to its neighboring children inside the parent.

In other words, a child's z-index is just its z-index within that parent, it can't be above or below the parent because it's inside of the parent.

Comment: Then you need to look into alternate solutions that don't use `z-index`. Though I don't know why one would "need" these divs in that format.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get the gray background to go behind the loading image you don't necessarily need 2 divs. You can instead combine it into one background -

```css
.se-pre-con {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: url(https://transfast.com/Projects/Transfast.UI/img/loadingimg.gif) center no-repeat 
              rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="se-pre-con"></div>
```

Comment: Supported in [nearly every major browser](http://caniuse.com/#search=multiple%20backgrounds)